# Make background color heading to reach the top of page and extend to both sides

Tags: html, css

This part of the code that can be found on http://jsbin.com/OWIbOYAl/1/edit

```
#header h1{
    color: #aaa; /*Gives header grey color*/
    background-color: #8F7AE0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;

}
```

I know I can set a negative margin but is there another way to do it? And why does the background color of my h1 have white space above it and to the sides anyway?

Answer (score 0):

```
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">
```

And

```
#header h1{
  color: #aaa; /*Gives header grey color*/
  background-color: #8F7AE0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin:0; padding:0;
}
```

In general tags come up cold from the browser with some defaults set that are not zero, *e.g. in this case margin and or padding had some non zero values pre set*.

These defaults can also vary from browser to browser so it's good to get used to setting everything that you are using and never relying on defaults.

Comment: i added that to body and it fixed the side problems but it does not extend to the top http://jsbin.com/OWIbOYAl/1/edit

Comment: wait what theres no link to your answer